# random velocity vector formula not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, math, physics

I am creating a game where on start, the ball needs to go in a random direction on the html canvas, but all ways have the same velocity. I am using this formula:

```
phi = 2*Math.PI*Math.random();
vx = speed * Math.cos(phi);
vy = speed * Math.sin(phi);
```

But it doesn't give me a constant velocity. Can someone correct the formula?

Here's the snippet:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
setInterval(render, 10);
var ball = {
 x: 250,
    y: 250,
    vx: 5 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * Math.random()),
    vy: 5 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * Math.random()),
    r: 5
}
function render() {
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ball.x += ball.vx;
    ball.y += ball.vy;
 context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not a constant velocity` ?

Comment: I mean that sometimes i want the ball to go at a constant speed across the canvas

Comment: It gives you constant *speed* which is magnitude of a velocity.

Comment: Your snippet does not show the same code as the excerpt atthe beginning of your function : you randomly choose two different angles for `vx` and `vy`. Use a `phi` variable (as you wrote in the beginning) and you should be fine

Comment: Your code as written adds a velocity to a position.  Units are a problem.  You are assuming a unit time step when you do it this way.  If you want to vary the time step dt you should write ball.x += ball.vx*dt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.random` returns new value on every call. You need to calcalute angle **once**.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
setInterval(render, 10);
var phi = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random() // you need the same angle
// because sin^2(phi) + cos^2(phi) = 1
var ball = {
 x: 250,
    y: 250,
    vx: 5 * Math.cos(phi),
    vy: 5 * Math.sin(phi),
    r: 5
}
function render() {
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ball.x += ball.vx;
    ball.y += ball.vy;
 context.beginPath();
    context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```